Quantum behavior of small atoms and molecules in a material
Edit:
I've given the answer from "anon" an upvote, but have not accepted it. I think we can do better. In reading some more on my question, I've been reminded that there are some key concepts that relate to whether a physical system is quantal or classical:

De Broglie wavelength
Heisenberg uncertainty
Relation of quantum energy scale to thermal energy
A dimensionless parameter akin to a Reynolds number

I remember studying the first two extensively in grad school. The last two are not ringing a bell for me. Should I be able to calculate a number for each of these four concepts for any particular atom or molecule or other physical system? That would seem to answer the question of whether the said particle is classical or quantal or intermediate.
If that's right, then my question becomes how to calculate each of the those four numbers for a selection of particles at room temperature and pressure, such as:

Atomic hydrogen
Carbon atom in a diamond
Oxygen molecule
A typical enzyme or protein molecule

I don't think I'm asking a different question from the one I originally posted. I think I'm asking the same question with more specificity.

Original question:

In a session with ChatGPT, it told me that even the smallest atoms and molecules in a gas or solid "behave in accordance with classical physics at room temperature." It said this is true even for the smallest unit-size material of all, atomic hydrogen gas. It explained it by saying that thermal energy drowns out quantum effects. That makes sense, but it surprised me because I thought that all atoms and molecules that are not very large are quantum particles whose behavior is governed by quantum mechanics. I thought, while macroscopic collections of those atoms and molecules behave classically, that "under the hood," the atoms were behaving quantum mechanically, even at room temperature.
Have I just been wrong, and the statement from ChatGPT is right?
I asked it for a reference to back up the statement. It suggested "Quantum Physics" by Resnick and "Atomic Physics" by Born​. I downloaded them and also looked in my old QM textbooks by Merzbacher and Cohen-Tannoudji, as well as the Feynman lectures. I didn't find anything about the quantum vs. classical behavior of individual atoms or molecules in a material.
So my question is, is it true that in a material (solid, liquid, or gas), even the smallest atoms and molecules behave in accordance with classical physics at room temperature?
And whether the answer is yes or no or something in between, what is a good reference that discusses the quantum vs. classical behavior of individual atoms and molecules in materials?

Please be cautious when using ChatGPT. It's just a language model, not a knowledge expert system. ChatGPT generates plausible text, consistent with its training data and input, but it doesn't know what it's talking about, and it has no way of representing or evaluating the truth of its utterances. It's only operating on linguistic structure, it is oblivious to the underlying logic and truth value of the statements it makes. It just generates sequences of statistically likely tokens. Yes, it can say true things, but it can also say complete nonsense, and it can't tell the difference.

Of course. That's why I came here to ask if what it said was true. Hopefully there's a human here who knows the answer.

This is my first post on this section of StackExchange. I see the question has three down votes. It could be helpful if someone could say what's wrong with it. Is it just because I cited ChatGPT? I could have just said that I read it somewhere, but instead said where I read it.

so what's the question you asked? Since classical physics is a subset of quantum mechanics: the atoms behave quantum mechanically is always correct.

The question is whether they behave classically.

Perhaps some of those downvotes are because of ChatGPT. Our site prohibits questions & answers generated by ChatGPT (etc), but it does permit questions like yours, that mention ChatGPT as a source. Please see  https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14693/123208 & links therein.

I expect the downvotes are because you considered changing your beliefs due to something ChatGPT said, which is a terrible life choice. ChatGPT will tell you anything and everything. It will tell you that the speed of light is constant, and that the speed of light is not constant. It will tell you that gravity is a force, and that gravity is not a force. It will tell you that light is a particle, that light is a wave, that it is both, and that it is neither, all with equal confidence. If you find that ChatGPT is affecting your beliefs, using it is harming you, and you should stop using it.

See e.g. the Drude model in solid state physics.

It is definitely not true that molecules behave in accordance with classical physics at room temperature.
I will give the most traditional example, which can be found in Chapter 40 of the Feynman lectures. The equipartition theorem, in statistical mechanics, says that the energy in a gas should be equally distributed between the various degrees of freedom that contribute quadratic terms to the total energy. Many properties of the gas depend on the number of these degrees of freedom. For example, in an adiabatic expansion of a classical ideal gas, $PV^\gamma$ is constant, where $\gamma = 1+\frac{2}{f}$ depends only on $f$, the number of degrees of freedom. This $\gamma$ is a number you can measure if you can determine the pressure and volume of a gas and perform adiabatic compressions, so it is a very concrete thing.
Furthermore, in a classical diatomic gas, there are 7 independent degrees of freedom. One way to describe these is as follows:

three translational degrees of freedom corresponding to the velocities of the center of mass of the molecule in three independent spatial directions;
two rotational degrees of freedom corresponding to the angular velocity about two nontrivial axes of rotation through the center of mass;
one vibrational degree of freedom corresponding to the relative velocity of the two atoms in the molecule;
and a second vibrational degree of freedom corresponding to the distance between the two atoms.

With 7 degrees of freedom, classical physics predicts $\gamma = 9/7$.
In quantum physics, the classical equipartion theorem doesn't hold. Each mode can only be excited to discrete energy levels, and there is not enough available energy at room temperature to excite the vibrational modes (they are "frozen out"). The molecule is extremely unlikely to get out of the ground state in those modes. However, there is plenty of energy to excite the translational and rotational modes, so the behavior of those modes can be approximated by the equipartiton theorem. Thus, quantum physics predicts that $\gamma = 7/5$ for diatomic gases at room temperature. (At lower temperatures, the rotational degrees of freedom begin to freeze out, and $\gamma$ rises. At higher temperatures, the vibrational degrees of freedom awaken, and $\gamma$ drops.)
In fact, experiments show that, for most diatomic gases, $\gamma \approx 7/5$ at room temperature, and that $\gamma$ is not constant, but declines as temperature rises. This establishes that the classical model is insufficient to describe the behavior of the molecules.

Thank you for this answer, which is interesting. But please see the edit of my question.
